# How does `git log --all --graph` get the branch pattern

Tags: git, version-control, branch

`git log --all --graph` shows my commits and draws a branch graph besides them.

But if I look at the raw information outputted by the `git log` command, the branch name is only available for the last commit in each branch (the branch tip).

Branches I've merged and deleted in the past don't even show up as names (they have no active tip), but still the graph renders them correctly.

How does git retrieve this information and how can I get the same information by parsing the output of some git command? (That is: Which git command produces the needed information?)

Comment: You may be interested in the [Git Internals chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) of the gitpro book. It explains how git saves changes internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to draw that graph are the parents for each commit. If a commit has more than one parent, it's a merge commit.

You can see this information with a plain `git log`. If a commit is a merge, you see a line `Merge: 0123456 9abcdef`. Alternatively you can use `git log --parents`. Then the `Commit:` line includes the commit's hash as well as all parents' hashes.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the `--parents` option. Now exporting with `--pretty=format:'{%n  "commit": "%H", %n  "parent": "%P", %n  "author": "%an <%ae>",%n  "date": "%ad",%n  "message": "%f", %n  "ref": "%d" %n},'` to get a JSON-like file for external parsing.