# How can `git log --graph` distinguish between branches?

Tags: git

Related to [How does `git log --all --graph` get the branch pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926527/how-does-git-log-all-graph-get-the-branch-pattern)

I am having trouble understanding how `git log --graph` creates a graph of a git history with a correct distinction between branches. Given the simple example of a master and a topic branch, I do not understand how git notices that the commits of the topic branch were not made on the master branch.

The related question linked above describes how a graph is created; the essence is that each commit points to at least one parent, and that fact yields a graph. What I do not understand is how git determines the difference between the following two (sketches of) graphs.

```
---x---A---B---x   (master)
    \         /
     D------C      (topic)

---x---D---C---x   (master)
    \         /
     A-------B
```

Given my understanding that branches are only pointers to commits, the above two graphs are identical. How does `git log --graph` manage to consistently display the first graph and not the second, even though commits A, B, C and D are all <strike>parents</strike> ancestors of master?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two reasons:

First: your first graph assumes that the branch `topic` is still around, and still points to `C`, which allows that segment of the graph to actually be labeled `topic`. If the branch was deleted, the graph would still be the same (and the merge commit would still probably say `merge branch 'topic'`), but the branch itself wouldn't have a label at its head.

Second: a commit can have multiple parents, but those parents aren't all equal; they're *ordered*. When you do `git merge`, the merge commit that's created will have the branch-merged-into as its first parent, and the branch-merged-in as its second parent. `git log` assumes this convention when it makes graphs: the first parent of a commit will be on the side that "continues straight", while the second parent will be on the side that "branches off". You can hand-craft a commit that violates this convention, and makes the graph do weird things, but there's not much reason to.

Comment: Thank you. The inequality between parent commits that you describe is exactly what I needed to know to make this click. The linked question told me that since commits have parents, a graph can be drawn; your answer now (finally) allows me to logically see why my two sketches are different. (Equal graphs, but different git-graphs.)

Answer (score 1):

Although a commit's parents are theoretically "equal" in terms of their contribution to the commit, they are stored as an *ordered* list. As such, you can refer to a commit's "first parent", its "second parent", etc.

The common commands for creating commits with multiple parents - git merge, git pull, etc - always put the commit that was initially checked out first in the list. Other git commands therefore distinguish the "first parent" as being the most likely to be "on the same branch".

For instance, git log has a "--first-parent" option, which generally has the effect of showing the commits "directly" to a branch, and skipping commits "merged into" the branch.

In the case of drawing a graph, the first parent can be prioritised as a straight line, and other parents drawn at an angle. This will *in most cases* result in long-lived branches showing the expected vertical line of commits.

Note that this is all completely independent of the branch labels - you could delete all your branches, and just ask for the graph of a particular commit's ancestors, and the algorithm would still choose some parents to be straight lines and some to be at an angle. Any branch labels which do exist are added as "decorations" (or not, depending on what other options you give the command).

Comment: Thank you. Let me expand with a follow-up question. Before asking this question I knew how to draw a graph (given that commits have at least one parent). With your answer, I now know why my two sketches are equal graphs, but different git-graphs (due to a list of merged-commit being an ordered list). Thus, I now see the difference in my two sketches. When would git ever draw these inconsistently, like you suggest? Isn't the idea of a "first parent commit" a sufficient requirement for consistent git-graphs?

Comment: @tedvangageldonk It's not that they're not *consistent*, just that they're not always *intuitive* - they don't necessarily follow what the user would think of as the "main" branch, because they don't know anything about branches. If you have several branches with merges going in both directions, they're not necessarily going to look like neat branches on the graph.

Answer (score 0):

### Fact-checking the question

#### The diagram

It is not useful to call two different commits `x` in the diagram. Naturally Git knows one commit from another, by their unique ID (SHA), but humans need unique identifiers of their own. Let's call them `X1` and `X2`.

Git does not actually draw diagrams, so it isn't clear where the posited diagram is supposed to come from. The closest you can get is `git log --graph`, which gives us this:

```
*   f0a9b98 (HEAD -> master) X2
|\  
| * b52962e (topic) C
| * 636aac2 D
* | dede634 B
* | a56cf5c A
|/  
* 18528e4 X1
```

You will notice that the graph is vertical, not horizontal as in your diagram.

You can get a better drawing by using a non-Git tool such as `gitk` or Sourcetree or whatever. For example, `gitk` gives this:

[image]

And Sourcetree gives this:

[image]

I do not know of *any* tool that would draw the graph you have drawn. No tool that I know draws time (parentage) horizontally; that doesn't mean there isn't one, of course.

#### What Git knows

You say:

> how git notices that the commits of the topic branch were not made on the master branch.

Git knows nothing about that, and the phrase "commits ... made on the master branch" is sort of meaningless. A commit has a parent (except for the root commit). That's all Git knows.

Under normal circumstances, when you make a commit, its parent is `HEAD` and then the `HEAD` pointer is moved to the new commit; moreover, under normal circumstances, `HEAD` is a branch name.

So before I made `B`, `master` was `A`, and therefore just after I made `B`, `master` was `B` and `A` had become the parent of `B`. But there is no Git knowledge that I was "on master" when I made `B`, and there is no knowledge that `master` was ever `A`. The only Git knowledge left over from that event is that `A` is the parent of `B`.

#### What branches are

You say

> my understanding that branches are only pointers to commits

Good. That is correct. However, that understanding seems to come and go. So let's firm it up. In the diagram, `master` is `X2` and `topic` is `C` and that is all there is to know about those branches.

#### What a parent is

You say:

> even though commits A, B, C and D are all parents of master

No. Every commit in the diagram except for `X2` and the root commit `X1` has exactly one parent. `master` in the diagram is `X2`, and `X2` has exactly two parents, `B` and `C`. That's because it is a merge commit. The other commits you mention are *reachable* from `X2`, and we can call them *ancestors* of `X2`, but they are not its parents, any more than your grandfather is your father.

It is useful, though — very useful — to speak of the *parent chain* leading from one commit to its parent to *its* parent and so on. The vertical lines in the diagram(s) are parent chains! The parent chain is what makes for reachability.

Parent chains also have the perhaps unfortunate consequence of making humans think that branches are long stringy things. They aren't. The parent chain `X2` -> `B` -> `A` -> `X1` is not a branch.

### So what's the question?

Let's stipulate that you're actually talking about `git log --graph`, since you mention it in the question. So the meaningful part of the question then would seem to be why `B` and `A` are in a straight vertical line with `X2` and `X1`, and not jutting out to the right like `C` and `D`.

The answer is: they don't have to be. It's sort of a matter of luck that they are. I've wound up in situations where that is *not* how the graph is drawn, and very confusing indeed was the result!

However, on the whole, the answer to that question is, as you've been told, that the parents of `X2` are not identical. One is the first parent and the other is the second parent. When I said `git merge`, `HEAD` was `master`, so that commit, the one that was `HEAD` at the time, is the first parent, namely `B`. Git has made some effort to ensure that `B` and its parent chain are shown to the left of the other parent of `X2`, namely `C`, and *its* parent chain.

Nevertheless, it is crucial to understand that there is nothing special about that way of drawing the topology. We can tell that `C` is a different branch from `master` because it has a branch name, `topic`. But that is a contingent fact; if we now delete `topic`, we erase the name, and there will be nothing inherent in the diagram to tell us what happened:

```
*   f0a9b98 (HEAD -> master) X2
|\  
| * b52962e C
| * 636aac2 D
* | dede634 B
* | a56cf5c A
|/  
* 18528e4 X1
```

That diagram is in fact totally equivalent to drawing `C` and `D` on the left, and `B` and `A` on the right — except that, as I already said, Git is trying to draw the merge commit's first parent and its parent chain on the left.

Still, you should not use that as a firm indication of anything. The way to know what order the parents of a merge commit come in is to ask Git:

```
$ git show
commit f0a9b985707d0967df2fa1a58f7ddefb400a5e24 (HEAD -> master)
Merge: dede634 b52962e
```

There are your merge commit's two parents in order; the first parent is `dede634`, which is `B`. *That* is what Git knows, and the layout of the diagram stems from that fact.

Comment: It does not seem to be documented (might be today but I remember searching for this long ago and not finding it), but: `git log --graph` always draws the *first* parent as a straight-down-`|`, and second-to-nth parent as a rightwards-down backslash. It does so even if it then has to immediately reverse directions on the rightwards-down-backslash so as to connect to something that's to the left. Other graph-drawing algorithms choose other methods of representing first-parent, or just don't bother (my horizontal graphs usually don't bother).

Comment: @torek I could swear I once got myself into a situation where the first parent was not straight down, but it was confusing so I could well have been confused. In any case `git log --graph` does sometimes make some pretty contorted diagrams...!

Comment: Thank you for your lengthy answer. I appreciate the effort. In my last sentence I will change 'parent' to 'ancestor' (my mistake!), and I'll specify that my graphs are sketches instead of actual output. On your end, I would correct "The vertical lines in the diagram(s) are parent-chains". Your definition of a parent-chain yields that all lines from X1 to X2 are parent-chains, not just the vertical lines, making that statement incorrect. As for structure, I would give this a rewrite. I'd start with the final section (containing the answer), and only then digress to branches/chains for clarity.

Comment: Hi @tedvangageldonk - all lines from X2 to X1 _are_ parent chains. Not sure what you think is "incorrect". As for the writing style / structure, hey, that's how I write. My response is aimed more at posterity.